# Vaadin 23 POST-Request does not connect

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I managed to set up a basic RequestController in Spring Boot using Vaadin 23 with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372808/vaadin-23-rest-api-and-ui-in-spring-boot-app).
Get Requests get through like intended, but for whatever reason, no POST request connects.

All I get is a response like this:

```
<!doctype html><!--
This file is auto-generated by Vaadin.
-->
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script initial="">window.Vaadin = window.Vaadin || {};window.Vaadin.VaadinLicenseChecker = {  maybeCheck: (productInfo) => {  }};window.Vaadin.devTools = window.Vaadin.devTools || {};window.Vaadin.devTools.createdCvdlElements = window.Vaadin.devTools.createdCvdlElements || [];window.Vaadin.originalCustomElementDefineFn = window.Vaadin.originalCustomElementDefineFn || window.customElements.define;window.customElements.define = function (tagName, constructor, ...args) {const { cvdlName, version } = constructor;if (cvdlName && version) {  const { connectedCallback } = constructor.prototype;  constructor.prototype.connectedCallback = function () {    window.Vaadin.devTools.createdCvdlElements.push(this);    if (connectedCallback) {      connectedCallback.call(this);    }  }}window.Vaadin.originalCustomElementDefineFn.call(this, tagName, constructor, ...args);};</script>
  <script initial="">window.Vaadin = window.Vaadin || {};window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors = window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors || [];const browserConsoleError = window.console.error.bind(window.console);console.error = (...args) => {    browserConsoleError(...args);    window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors.push(args);};window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {const location=source+':'+lineno+':'+colno;window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors.push([message, '('+location+')']);};window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', e => {    window.Vaadin.ConsoleErrors.push([e.reason]);});</script>
  <script initial="">window.Vaadin = window.Vaadin || {};window.Vaadin.TypeScript= {};</script>
  <meta name="_csrf_parameter" content="_csrf">
  <meta name="_csrf_header" content="X-CSRF-TOKEN">
  <meta name="_csrf" content="6b25f646-7020-473e-a73e-74719d95d6e2"><base href=".">
  <script type="text/javascript">window.JSCompiler_renameProperty = function(a) { return a;}</script>
  <script type="module">import { inject } from "/project/ui/VAADIN/@vite-plugin-checker-runtime";
inject({
  overlayConfig: {},
  base: "/project/ui/VAADIN/",
});</script>
  <script type="module" src="/project/ui/VAADIN/@vite/client"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body, #outlet {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style> <!-- index.ts is included here automatically (either by the dev server or during the build) -->
  <script type="module" src="/project/ui/VAADIN/generated/vite-devmode.ts"></script>
  <script type="module" src="/project/ui/VAADIN/generated/vaadin.ts"></script>
  <style>.v-reconnect-dialog,.v-system-error {position: absolute;color: black;background: white;top: 1em;right: 1em;border: 1px solid black;padding: 1em;z-index: 10000;max-width: calc(100vw - 4em);max-height: calc(100vh - 4em);overflow: auto;} .v-system-error {color: indianred;pointer-events: auto;} .v-system-error h3, .v-system-error b {color: red;}</style>
  <style>[hidden] { display: none !important; }</style>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="project">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#ffffff">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <link sizes="16x16" rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/icon-16x16.png" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="32x32" rel="icon" href="icons/icon-32x32.png" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="96x96" rel="icon" href="icons/icon-96x96.png?1713631522" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="180x180" rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/icon-180x180.png?-533695959" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2048x2732" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-2048x2732.png?-1201942874" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2732x2048" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2732x2048.png?266277477" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1668x2388" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1668x2388.png?-1539431919" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2388x1668" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2388x1668.png?598404288" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1668x2224" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1668x2224.png?1678662124" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2224x1668" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2224x1668.png?746534339" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1620x2160" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1620x2160.png?-770300885" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2160x1620" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2160x1620.png?-525914264" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1536x2048" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1536x2048.png?713310212" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2048x1536" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2048x1536.png?1750378074" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1284x2778" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1284x2778.png?1984992155" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2778x1284" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2778x1284.png?389448020" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1170x2532" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1170x2532.png?-743684054" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2532x1170" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2532x1170.png?2114630635" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1125x2436" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1125x2436.png?-688834165" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2436x1125" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2436x1125.png?-221066565" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1242x2688" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1242x2688.png?-313405698" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2688x1242" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2688x1242.png?20506735" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="828x1792" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-828x1792.png?1276193420" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1792x828" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-1792x828.png?1725405299" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1242x2208" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-1242x2208.png?1508207887" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="2208x1242" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-2208x1242.png?-167637239" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="750x1334" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-750x1334.png?-1346703542" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1334x750" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-1334x750.png?-1196513029" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="640x1136" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="icons/icon-640x1136.png?893776263" type="image/png">
  <link sizes="1136x640" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="icons/icon-1136x640.png?-1834685424" type="image/png">
  <script>if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  });
}</script>
 </head>
 <body><!-- This outlet div is where the views are rendered -->
  <div id="outlet"></div>
  <script>window.Vaadin = window.Vaadin || {};
window.Vaadin.registrations = window.Vaadin.registrations || [];
window.Vaadin.registrations.push({"is":"flow/SpringInstantiator","version":"23.3.3"},{"is":"routing/server","version":"23.3.3"},{"is":"flow/AtmospherePushConnection","version":"2.7.3.slf4jvaadin4"},{"is":"java","version":"17.0.5"});</script><vaadin-dev-tools url="VAADIN/push" springbootlivereloadport="35729"></vaadin-dev-tools>
 </body>
</html>
```

My RequestController:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
@RestController
public class TestRestController {
    

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/secondget")
    public String secondGet() {
        return "Hello World #2!";
    }

    @PostMapping(
        value = "/postbody")
    public String post(@RequestBody String body) {
        return "Received: " + body;
    }
}
```

I tried setting "consumes" and "produces" in @PostMapping to various types, but none work. For whatever reason the method is never called. I tried using Postman on this to send my request. When trying to send a GET-Request I get the error, that the method is not allowed, so I guess that my application has registered this endpoint as POST method...

My goal is to send json to my method. So I already tried including 'Content-Type': 'application/json' in my request header (Postman does that automatically)

Could someone please help?

**EDIT**

application.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/project
server.port=${PORT:8080}

vaadin.urlMapping=/ui/*
```

SecurityConfiguration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    public static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/project";
    public static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/";

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /**
     * userDetailsService is required for the Remember Me
     * https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/remember-me.html
     * 
     * @param userDetailsService
     */
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"))
            .permitAll();

        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);


        http.rememberMe().key("ABC")
            .tokenValiditySeconds(2 * 24 * 60 * 60)
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);

        http.logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/*.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your complete code
For example, upload it to github

Comment: @Jilliss: Unfortunately I cannot provide the whole code due to company regulations, so I edited my post and added the application.properties and SecurityConfiguration. There are no other places in the project where anything should tamper with the configuration.

Comment: POST requests are by default secured by CSRF. Please configure it appropriate.

Comment: Ok I read some articles about Spring Boot and CSRF attacks. I understand that I do not necessarily need csrf protection if I have my endpoints secured through for Example authentication data inside my request body (for post). So when I define an abstract RequestBody, that has username + password, or any arbitrary token sent inside a json body and I check with my own services that username + password or the token is correct, then I can just disable csrf, am I right?

Comment: The part that I don't understand is, what about my ui part? I guess my ui still needs some sort of csrf protection?